# Replace previous plot with each mouse click in matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, plot

Hi im trying to have the first part of my program plot a line from the origin with length 10 in the direction of where the mouse clicks in the plot area. i currently have this:

```
[gx,gy,b] = ginput(1);

theta = atand(gy/gx);
theta = theta*(pi/180);
polar(theta,8,'-k')
```

within a loop of while b~=3. ie trying to say whilst clicking the left mouse button, i want it to plot a line in the direction of the click, and when the right button is pressed...move onto the rest of the program with the line staying in the position of the last left click made.

Also, when each left click is made, the previous line plotted should be replaced by the new one. ie only one line on the screen at a time.

thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The following script works for me, if I interpreted your question correctly.

```
figure
R=10; % desired line length
polar(0,R) % empty polar plot

b=0;
while b~=3
    [gx,gy,b]=ginput(1);
    if b~=3 % not a right mouse click
        theta=atan(gy/gx);
        if gx<0
            theta=theta+pi; % this is needed, because atan(gy/gx) will always range from -pi/2 to pi/2
        end
        polar([0 theta],[0 R],'-k')
    end
end
```

**What it does**

A figure is made with a polar plot with `R=10`. Next, the loop is initiated. In the loop, the `ginput()` function is called. Its outputs are stored in `gx` and `gy`. Next, it is checked whether or not the right mouse button was pressed. If not, `gx` and `gy` are used like you did with the arctangent. If `gx<0`, the arctangent still will calculate an angle `theta` between -pi/2 and pi/2, which is on the right half of the polar plot. Therefore, pi is added to theta if this is the case. A black line is plotted from origin `[0,0]` with a radius of 10 and the calculated angle theta.

If the right mouse is clicked anywhere in the figure, the while loop is left and MATLAB continues. Note that `gx` and `gy` contain the position of your right mouse click, not the previous (not right) mouse click.

Was this the intended behaviour? If not, let me know, then I can see if my code can be improved.